# BeautifulSoup find only elements where an attribute contains a sub-string? Is this possible?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a call to `find_all()` in my `BeautifulSoup` code. This works currently to get me all images, but if I wanted to target only images which have a sub-string of "placeholder" in their `src`, how could I do this?

```
for t in soup.find_all('img'):  # WHERE img.href.contains("placeholder")
```

Comment: Presumably you meant the `src` attribute, not the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can [pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) in the `src` keyword argument:

```
for t in soup.find_all('img', src=lambda x: x and 'placeholder' in x):
```

Or, a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

for t in soup.find_all('img', src=re.compile(r'placeholder')):
```

Or, instead of `find_all()`, use [`select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for t in soup.select('img[src*=placeholder]'):
```

Comment: or use CSS selectors: `soup.select('img[src*=placeholder]')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's I would actually do too, thanks :) I'll include into the answer.

Comment: You guys are awsome. I would really appreciate if someone could elaborate a bit more on how css selectors work in bs4, I find it kind confusing when compared with scrapy for example, in scrapy you can copy from element inspector, but it seem that doesn't work on bs4

Comment: What does the apostrophe after src represent?